# How to count transactions per day in the last 1 month on LARAVEL

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have data on transaction table like this:

```
___________________________________________________________________
| id  | cash    | total   | invoice_number | created_at           |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
|  1  | 25000   | 25000   | TR-3435345345  |  2022-07-01 14:24:36 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
```

What I want to do is I want to count the number of transactions per day. In other words, the expected output is like this:

```
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...]
```

but the output that comes out is:

```
[1]
```

This is the syntax I wrote:

```
$transaction = Transaction::select('*')->groupBy('created_at')->whereBetween('created_at', [Carbon::now()->firstOfMonth(), Carbon::now()->endOfMonth()])->count();
```

Is there a way for me to get the output as expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code for last month chart record.

```
$lastMonth = CarbonPeriod::create(Carbon::now()->subDays(29), Carbon::now());
$lastMonthOrders = [];
foreach ($lastMonth as $date) {
   $lastMonthOrders['days'][] = $date->format("l");
   
   // Here is the count part that you need
   $lastMonthOrders['orders'][] = DB::table('orders')->whereDate('created_at', '=', $date)->count(); 
}
$dashboard_infos['lastMonthOrders'] = $lastMonthOrders;
```

Output:

```
array:2 [▼
  "days" => array:30 [▼
    0 => "Friday"
    1 => "Saturday"
    2 => "Sunday"
    3 => "Monday"
    4 => "Tuesday"
    5 => "Wednesday"
    6 => "Thursday"
    7 => "Friday"
    8 => "Saturday"
    9 => "Sunday"
    10 => "Monday"
    11 => "Tuesday"
    12 => "Wednesday"
    13 => "Thursday"
    14 => "Friday"
    15 => "Saturday"
    16 => "Sunday"
    17 => "Monday"
    18 => "Tuesday"
    19 => "Wednesday"
    20 => "Thursday"
    21 => "Friday"
    22 => "Saturday"
    23 => "Sunday"
    24 => "Monday"
    25 => "Tuesday"
    26 => "Wednesday"
    27 => "Thursday"
    28 => "Friday"
    29 => "Saturday"
  ]
  "orders" => array:30 [▼
    0 => 0
    1 => 0
    2 => 0
    3 => 0
    4 => 0
    5 => 1
    6 => 0
    7 => 0
    8 => 0
    9 => 0
    10 => 0
    11 => 0
    12 => 0
    13 => 3
    14 => 0
    15 => 0
    16 => 0
    17 => 0
    18 => 0
    19 => 0
    20 => 0
    21 => 0
    22 => 0
    23 => 0
    24 => 0
    25 => 0
    26 => 0
    27 => 2
    28 => 0
    29 => 0
  ]
]
```

Modify based on your project.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are getting a count of the result set so it will always return a single row. instead, if you use count in a select statement then you will get the count value by the group. and in group by also you are considering the whole DateTime instead of that do the group by only `date(cloumn_name)`

```
-- create a table
CREATE TABLE orders (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  invoice_number varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  cash INTEGER(11) NOT NULL,
  create_at varchar(50)
);
-- insert some values
INSERT INTO orders VALUES (1, 'fdsgfdsgds11', 100,"2022-07-02 14:24:36");
INSERT INTO orders VALUES (2, 'fdsgfdsgds12', 200,"2022-07-02 15:24:36");
INSERT INTO orders VALUES (3, 'fdsgfdsgds13', 300,"2022-07-02 15:24:36");
INSERT INTO orders VALUES (4, 'fdsgfdsgds14', 400,"2022-07-01 15:24:36");
INSERT INTO orders VALUES (5, 'fdsgfdsgds15', 500,"2022-07-01 15:24:36");
INSERT INTO orders VALUES (6, 'fdsgfdsgds16', 600,"2022-07-03 15:24:36");
INSERT INTO orders VALUES (7, 'fdsgfdsgds17', 700,"2022-08-03 15:24:36");
-- fetch some values
SELECT count(id),date(create_at) FROM orders where date(create_at) between '2022-07-01' and '2022-07-30' group by date(create_at) order by date(create_at);
```

output

```
2|2022-07-01
3|2022-07-02
1|2022-07-03
```

if the date is not present in the return row then for that date order count will be zero. In this way, you no need to execute a DB query for each day. it will reduce your read operation. otherwise you need to run minimum 30 query per month.